# Over 8 minutes to read a 1 GB side input view (List)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We have a 1 GB List that was created using View.asList() method on beam sdk 2.0. We are trying to iterate through every member of the list and do, for now, nothing significant with it (we just sum up a value). Just reading this 1 GB list is taking about 8 minutes to do so (and that was after we set the workerCacheMb=8000, which we *think* means that the worker cache is 8 GB). (If we don't set the workerCacheMB to 8000, it takes over 50 minutes before we just kill the job.). We're using a n1-standard-32 instance, which should have more than enough RAM. There is ONLY a single thread reading this 8GB list. We know this because we create a dummy PCollection of one integer and we use it to then read this 8GB ViewList side-input.

It should not take 6 minutes to read in a 1 GB list, especially if there's enough RAM. **EVEN** if the list were materialized to disk (which it shouldn't be), a normal *single* NON-ssd disk can read data at 100 MB/s, so it should take ~10 seconds to read in this absolute worst case scenario....

What are we doing wrong? Did we discover a dataflow bug? Or maybe the workerCachMB is really in KB instead of MB? We're tearing our hair out here....

Comment: In the implementation of side inputs for Dataflow, they must be serialized to the network. The side input is read from cloud storage. Therefore, it is normal that this step is slow. I'll look into whether 1gb/8min is too slow, but know that iterating over a whole PCollectionView is bound to be slow.

What kind of operation do you want to try over this collection that it needs to be used as a side input?

Comment: Even with seriliazation to google cloud storage, I'm assuming that we should be as fast a single non-SSD hard disk (~100MBs, or ~0.8Gbs), which should mean around 10 seconds to load the binary data.

That said, to answer your question: we need run a single-threaded operation on all the elements to see which elements in the list can be merged or not. We have something similar to 1million RangeSet objects and we need to merge each of them with each other until there is no more merging possible. Then, we end up with the minimum rangeSet objects that span the initial 1million rangesets

Comment: This sort of operation sounds like it could be accomplished by a CombineFn. You'd need to implement a CombineFn that is commutative and associative, so that it can be performed on the Map workers and the reduce workers with high performance.
If this is not possible, you may also consider trying a GroupByKey, where every element has the same key. In this case, the would read from Shuffle, rather than from GCS. This may be faster, but I am not quite sure.

Comment: If you'd like, you can submit a question with specifics of your data structures and operation, and we can try to work on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setWorkervacheMb(1000). 1000 MB = Around 1GB. It will pick the side input from cache of each worker node and that will be fast.

```
DataflowWorkerHarnessOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create().cloneAs(DataflowWorkerHarnessOptions.class);
        options.setWorkerCacheMb(1000);
```

Is it really required to iterate 1 GB of side input data every time or you are need some specific data to get during iteration?

In case you need specific data then you should get it by passing specific index in the list. Getting data specific to index is much faster operation then iterating whole 1GB data.

Answer (score 0):

After checking with the Dataflow team, the rate of 1GB in 8 minutes sounds about right.

Side inputs in Dataflow are always serialized. This is because to have a side input, a *view* of a PCollection must be generated. Dataflow does this by serializing it to a special indexed file.

If you give more information about your use case, we can help you think of ways of doing it in a faster manner.